# How to run a background service nonstop in Android 13?

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, background-service, foreground-service

[link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) 
*While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely. When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's background services, just as if the app had called the services' Service.stopSelf() methods.*

This background service limitation is for Android 8.0 and above. 
Here's the task that needs to be done with the app in foreground, background, closed or even when it was not started:

Check the speed using gps sensor every 2 minutes -> if it is more than a threshold, start the foreground service to send continuous data of location and speed to the server -> Stop the foreground service after a certain criterion is met -> Back to step 1.

I tried implementing background service, but it stopped after a few minutes of killing the app (swiping the app from the background).

There is a react native package called notifee, which has foreground service as one of its features. This allows users to start a foreground service, but when the task is done, it is stopped and there is no way to start it again.

Comment: For Long running task handling use WorkManager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager